# Полноэкранный режим с масштабированием

Tags: c, windows, winapi

У меня есть функция для смены режима отображения окна (полноэкранный/оконный):

```
void sr_WindowToggleFullscreen(void) {
    static WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPrevPlacement;

    if (!sr_windowIsFullscreen) {
        GetWindowPlacement(sr_windowHandler, &windowPrevPlacement);
        SetWindowLong(sr_windowHandler, GWL_STYLE, WS_BORDER);
        SetWindowLong(sr_windowHandler, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOPMOST);
        ShowWindow(sr_windowHandler, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
        sr_windowIsFullscreen = true;
    } else {
        SetWindowLong(sr_windowHandler, GWL_STYLE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE);
        SetWindowLong(sr_windowHandler, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0L);
        SetWindowPlacement(sr_windowHandler, &windowPrevPlacement);
        ShowWindow(sr_windowHandler, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        sr_windowIsFullscreen = false;
    }
}
```

Она дает следующие результаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе в полноэкранный режим вся клиентская область масштабировалась до размеров экрана? Что-то типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] <sub>*Здесь просто растянул клиентскую область до размеров экрана в фотошопе.*</sub>